# Отправка формы с данными и фалом по ajax

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ajax, form

Есть форма заказа, в ней есть поля имя, контакты, описание и поле для загрузки одного файла. Подскажите как правильно реализовать отправку этой формы по ajax c jquery, что бы и обычные инпуты собрать и файл ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
// Переменная куда будут располагаться данные файлов

var files;

// Вешаем функцию на событие
// Получим данные файлов и добавим их в переменную




$('input[type=file]').change(function(){
    files = this.files;
});

// Вешаем функцию ан событие click и отправляем AJAX запрос с данными файлов

$('.submit.button').click(function( event ){
    event.stopPropagation(); // Остановка происходящего
    event.preventDefault();  // Полная остановка происходящего

// Создадим данные формы и добавим в них данные файлов из files

var data = new FormData();
$.each( files, function( key, value ){
    data.append( key, value );
});

// Отправляем запрос

$.ajax({
    url: './submit.php?uploadfiles',
    type: 'POST',
    data: data,
    cache: false,
    dataType: 'json',
    processData: false, // Не обрабатываем файлы (Don't process the files)
    contentType: false, // Так jQuery скажет серверу что это строковой запрос
    success: function( respond, textStatus, jqXHR ){

        // Если все ОК

        if( typeof respond.error === 'undefined' ){
            // Файлы успешно загружены, делаем что нибудь здесь

            // выведем пути к загруженным файлам в блок '.ajax-respond'

            var files_path = respond.files;
            var html = '';
            $.each( files_path, function( key, val ){ html += val +'<br>'; } )
            $('.ajax-respond').html( html );
        }
        else{
            console.log('ОШИБКИ ОТВЕТА сервера: ' + respond.error );
        }
    },
    error: function( jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown ){
        console.log('ОШИБКИ AJAX запроса: ' + textStatus );
    }
});

});
```

Comment: Спасибо, а ты не знаешь как отсылать CSRF токен при отсылке POST запроса через AJAX Jquery ?

Comment: //примерно как-то так
$.ajax({
          url: "test",
                    data: ...,
                    type: "POST",
                    beforeSend: function(request) {
        return request.setRequestHeader('X-CSRF-Token', $("meta[name='csrf-token']").attr('content'));
    },

Comment: Спасибо за помощь!